# MaskedTextBox como colocar máscara dinamicamente no Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Como faço para ocultar a máscara e apenas mostrá-la conforme o usuário for preenchendo o campo (dinamicamente)? Ex.:
Numa data xx/xx/xxxx ir aparecendo a barra apenas quando chegasse nela.
Nos eventos do componente só encontrei algo relacionado quando o foco é mudado para o componente, quando clico no componente ou quando aperto alguma tecla do teclado, mas nada que faça dessa forma.
Estou usando o Windows Forms C# .NetFramework 4.8 Visual Studio 2019

Comment: A resposta está na sua pergunta. Para criar esse efeito você vai precisar utilizar todos esses eventos e implementar seus comportamentos.

Answer (score 0):

Para criar dinamicamente voce pode inicialmente colocar um `MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();` e colocar todas as configurações que deseja e para instaciar, um `Controls.Add(maskedTextBox);`. E para fazer o que voce deseja, voce pode fazer, com que conforme cada tamanho da string adicione a barra em um evento de mudança de texto, olhe um exemplo, eu utilizei o Método `DynamicallyMaskedTexBox()` para criar a MaskedTextBox e `maskedTextBox_TexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` para o evento, olhe o exemplo:

```cs
namespace Forms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox;

        public Form1()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            DynamicallyMaskedTexBox();
        }

        private void DynamicallyMaskedTexBox()
        {
            
            maskedTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();
            maskedTextBox.Name = "MaskedTexBox1";
            maskedTextBox.Location = new Point(12,70);
            maskedTextBox.Width = 100;
            maskedTextBox.Height = 20;
            
            maskedTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(maskedTextBox_TexChanged);

            Controls.Add(maskedTextBox);
        }

        private void maskedTextBox_TexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string maskedText = "00000000";
            try
            {
                if(maskedTextBox.Mask.Length < maskedText.Length/4)
                {
                    maskedTextBox.Mask += "00";
                    maskedTextBox.SelectionStart = maskedTextBox.Text.Length;
                    maskedTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                }
                else if(maskedTextBox.Mask.Length == maskedText.Length/4)
                {
                    maskedTextBox.Mask += "/";
                    
                }
                else if(maskedTextBox.Mask.Length < maskedText.Length/2+1)
                {
                    maskedTextBox.Mask += "0";
                }
                else if (maskedTextBox.Mask.Length == maskedText.Length / 2+1)
                {
                    maskedTextBox.Mask += "/";
                }
                else if(maskedTextBox.Mask.Length >= maskedText.Length /2+2 && maskedTextBox.Mask.Length < maskedText.Length+2)
                {
                    maskedTextBox.Mask += "0";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }
}
```